# aMember Pro to PayPal checkout not working

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions, amember

We are currently using “aMember Pro Version 3.1.2,” and are experiencing an issue with the PAYPAL plugin checkout.

HERE’S THE PROBLEM:

1. The member selects their “subscription,” selects “PAYPAL” as their method of payment, then clicks the “Subscribe” button to checkout.
2. They arrive on the 2nd page that says:

“You will be automatically redirected to secure payment page in about 2 seconds”

1. They then arrive on the 3rd and last page which is a PayPal URL:

https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=HhJUVdQR6TiXtJ79AF7kp7ycke9qtt43VcRfeaz_nyUrK-iL0P7HxV02RHO&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8dd75b1e1ec3ad97b7af62835dd81d5d52

With this error message:

“The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again.”

FACT #1:  If the member selects another payment checkout such as “CLICKBANK,” everything is working fine (i.e. they are able to checkout).

FACT #2: The PayPal IPN is working fine, as we are currently receiving notifications from PayPal

FACT #3: Every time the member attempts to checkout with “PAYPAL,” it registers in our aMember admin and displays the correct “Paid” and “Status” info (e.g. Paid = NO, Status = Non-Paid).

FACT #4: PayPal checkout is not working for both existing and new member registrations.

Answer (score 0):

It could be with something that is getting passed over in the redirect, such as the variables you are posting over to PayPal.  You could try capturing the request and posting them here and I can take a look at them to see what may be causing the issue, or provide a link to your checkout.